# cant change iframe in firefox. similar to sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, cross-domain, sandbox

I 've  iframe on my page. the src of iframe is page from another domain(I have Cross-domain communication with them). When I open iframe, then I need to change it with another page. For  Chrome I was doing like that:

```
    frames['iframe_id'].location.href=URL;
iframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin';
```

how can I do  the similar thing in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

solved, and simple Way:
var iframe = document.getElementsByName("id");
document.getElementById('id').src = URL;

Answer (score 0):

solved. Firefox does not need something like sandbox.